# react: reusable event handler for setstate

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component with some fields (dropdowns, text input areas etc.) each has onclick handler like:

```
    handleTitleChange(v){
        this.setState({
            draft: {...this.state.draft, title: v}
        })
    }

    handleDescriptionChange(v){
        this.setState({
            draft: {...this.state.draft, description: v}
        })
    }
...... about 5 more
```

Notice here the state is an object with different keys.
How I can make a unique handler with the field of the state object passed to the handle function? something like:

```
handleFieldChange(fieldName, v){
    this.setState({
        draft: {...this.state.draft, <fieldName>: v}
    })
}
```

So I can reuse it in different component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following syntax to achieve this:

```
handleFieldChange(fieldName, v){
    this.setState({
        draft: {...this.state.draft, [fieldname]: v}
    })
}
```